# How are pandas objects able to be passed into numpy functions?

Tags: pandas, numpy

Curious how this works under the hood. Did numpy just build functionality to handle pandas objects or is there something else going on here?

```
data = pandas.Series([1,2,3,4])
numpy.sqrt(data) # returns pandas.Series
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to overriding `__array__` as the other answer mentions:

`pd.Series`: it implements `__array_ufunc__` so it overrides the `ufunc` behaviour with that, including how the output should look like.

`pd.DataFrame`: it doesn't implement that method, but implements `__array_wrap__`; and this gives the control for how output should look like.

See [here](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/ufuncs.html#output-type-determination) for the output type determination. Pandas [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/dsintro.html#dataframe-interoperability-with-numpy-functions) also mentions the series case.

Answer (score 1):

The dataframe (and Series) has an `__array__` method:

```
In [138]: df
Out[138]: 
   Account1  Account2  m_solution
0       150        18 -117.857143
1       130      1200  104.586466
2       150        18 -117.857143
3       106      1200   88.793262
4       150        18 -117.857143
5       170      1200  127.810219
6       150       138   -6.250000
7      1056      1200   67.404255
In [139]: df.__array__()
Out[139]: 
array([[ 150.        ,   18.        , -117.85714286],
       [ 130.        , 1200.        ,  104.58646617],
       [ 150.        ,   18.        , -117.85714286],
       [ 106.        , 1200.        ,   88.79326187],
       [ 150.        ,   18.        , -117.85714286],
       [ 170.        , 1200.        ,  127.81021898],
       [ 150.        ,  138.        ,   -6.25      ],
       [1056.        , 1200.        ,   67.40425532]])
```

Equivalently you can get the array with:

```
In [140]: df.values
Out[140]: 
array([[ 150.        ,   18.        , -117.85714286],
       [ 130.        , 1200.        ,  104.58646617],
       [ 150.        ,   18.        , -117.85714286],
       [ 106.        , 1200.        ,   88.79326187],
       [ 150.        ,   18.        , -117.85714286],
       [ 170.        , 1200.        ,  127.81021898],
       [ 150.        ,  138.        ,   -6.25      ],
       [1056.        , 1200.        ,   67.40425532]])
In [141]: df.to_numpy()
Out[141]: 
array([[ 150.        ,   18.        , -117.85714286],
       [ 130.        , 1200.        ,  104.58646617],
       [ 150.        ,   18.        , -117.85714286],
       [ 106.        , 1200.        ,   88.79326187],
       [ 150.        ,   18.        , -117.85714286],
       [ 170.        , 1200.        ,  127.81021898],
       [ 150.        ,  138.        ,   -6.25      ],
       [1056.        , 1200.        ,   67.40425532]])
```

I think `pandas` docs encourage the use of `to_numpy`.

The data of the frame is stored in one or more arrays (depending on dtypes).  Whether the array you get these ways is actually that array, a view or copy may vary.

Code for `__array__`

```
Signature: df.__array__(dtype=None) -> 'np.ndarray'
Docstring: <no docstring>
Source:   
    def __array__(self, dtype=None) -> np.ndarray:
        return np.asarray(self._values, dtype=dtype)
```

See also `Series.__array__`.  It's a bit different.

and `Series.__array_wrap__`:

```
S.__array_wrap__(
    result: 'np.ndarray',
    context: 'Optional[Tuple[Callable, Tuple[Any, ...], int]]' = None,
)
Docstring:
Gets called after a ufunc and other functions.

Parameters
----------
result: np.ndarray
    The result of the ufunc or other function called on the NumPy array
    returned by __array__
```

Comment: Thanks, seems like numpy functions operate on the __array__ method but how does it preserve the return type? E.g. returning pandas.Series instead of numpy.array?

Comment: Looking at the methods of a `Series`, I see `__array_wrap__`.  A Series isn't a subclass of `ndarray`, but it appears to have many of the methods that make it behave as one.